# Swift Escape Character '\' being added to the string

Tags: swift, string

I need to make an API Call from Swift 3.0 that is SailsJS Platform.

I need to make the following blue print route.

URL: https://[myapiCall]/[model]?where={"approvalStatus":{"not":"Approved"}}

This works perfectly with Browser/Postman

In Swift I created this url string as follows:

```
var URL:String = "https://<myapiCall>/<model>?where={\"approvalStatus\":{\"not\":\"Approved\"}}"
```

The resulting code being called includes the escape characters.

I have tried many alternative ways.

1. without escape characters, it breaks the string.
2. tried replacing the escape character '\' in the final URL with empty String but to replace we need to find \ as "\". And the code starts looking for \ instead of \ -_-

Comment: When using GET requests, try and add use the string with percentage escapes: URL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't encoding it properly.  Here's some working code from a Swift 3 playground:

```
if var components = URLComponents(string: "https://server/model") {
    var query = [ "approvalStatus" : [ "not" : "Approved" ] ]

    var serialized = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: query, options: .init(rawValue: 0))
    var jsonStr = String(data: serialized, encoding: .utf8)
    let queryItem = URLQueryItem(name: "where", value: jsonStr)
    components.queryItems = [queryItem]

    print (components.url!)
}
```

This prints `"https://server/model?where=%7B%22approvalStatus%22:%7B%22not%22:%22Approved%22%7D%7D"`